# Vue data updating issue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In Vue there is computed method loadLang for translate, i load that into mounted lifecycle.

[image]

when i run that, its not updating translate (i18n.t) data. but when i click Vue developer tools component after that updated data was displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, have a look here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/join.html

There's a link to a forum, https://forum.vuejs.org/.

Comment: You can also check out discord https://vue.land/